# SQL Two JOINS same table different values

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, inner-join

I am making multiple inner join:s in order to get data out of database.
Depending on what RelationshipType I choose to use the outcome changes.

```
INNER JOIN [SERVER01].[ServiceManager].[dbo].[BaseManagedEntity] AS BMEt ON rel.TargetEntityId = BMEt.BaseManagedEntityId
INNER JOIN [SERVER01].[ServiceManager].[dbo].[RelationshipType] AS RT ON rel.RelationshipTypeId = RT.RelationshipTypeId 
    AND RT.RelationshipTypeName = 'Cireson.AssetManagement.HardwareAssetHasLocation'
```

AND

```
INNER JOIN [SERVER01].[ServiceManager].[dbo].[BaseManagedEntity] AS BMEt ON rel.TargetEntityId = BMEt.BaseManagedEntityId
INNER JOIN [SERVER01].[ServiceManager].[dbo].[RelationshipType] AS RT ON rel.RelationshipTypeId = RT.RelationshipTypeId 
    AND RT.RelationshipTypeName = 'Cireson.AssetManagement.HardwareAssetHasOrganization'
```

The value I want on both above JOINs is in BMEt.Name.

Iv'e tried to just change the names BMEt to BMEt2, RT to RT2 for the second one and hoped that would do it. But then I get no data. (no errors just no data)

I've also tried to use IN like this:

```
INNER JOIN [SERVER01].[ServiceManager].[dbo].[BaseManagedEntity] AS BMEt ON rel.TargetEntityId = BMEt.BaseManagedEntityId
INNER JOIN [SERVER01].[ServiceManager].[dbo].[RelationshipType] AS RT ON rel.RelationshipTypeId = RT.RelationshipTypeId 
    AND RT.RelationshipTypeName IN ('Cireson.AssetManagement.HardwareAssetHasOrganization','Cireson.AssetManagement.HardwareAssetHasLocation')
```

I then get both values but in the same column obviously. Is it possible to split this into two columns or how should I retrieve the data?

**FULL QUERY**

```
DECLARE @OSBuild AS VARCHAR(100)='10.0.19042'

SELECT VRS.[ResourceID] AS 'ResourceID'
       ,VRS.[Name0] AS 'Computername'
       ,VRS.[Resource_Domain_OR_Workgr0] AS 'Domain'
       ,BIOS.SerialNumber0 AS 'Serialnumber'
       ,BMEt.Name AS 'Location'
FROM [SERVER02].[dbo].[v_R_System] as VRS
INNER JOIN [SERVER02].[dbo].[v_GS_OPERATING_SYSTEM] AS vGSOS on vGSOS.[ResourceID] = VRS.[ResourceID] 
INNER JOIN [SERVER02].[dbo].v_GS_PC_BIOS AS BIOS ON BIOS.[ResourceID] = VRS.[ResourceID]
INNER JOIN [SERVER01].[ServiceManager].[dbo].[MT_Cireson$AssetManagement$HardwareAsset] AS HWA ON BIOS.SerialNumber0 = HWA.SerialNumber_C8CF2E89_7A83_1C26_0AD0_887DF9140D5A COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
INNER JOIN [SERVER01].[ServiceManager].[dbo].relationship AS rel ON rel.SourceEntityId = HWA.BaseManagedEntityId

INNER JOIN [SERVER01].[ServiceManager].[dbo].[BaseManagedEntity] AS BMEt ON rel.TargetEntityId = BMEt.BaseManagedEntityId
INNER JOIN [SERVER01].[ServiceManager].[dbo].[RelationshipType] AS RT ON rel.RelationshipTypeId = RT.RelationshipTypeId 
    AND RT.RelationshipTypeName IN ('Cireson.AssetManagement.HardwareAssetHasOrganization','Cireson.AssetManagement.HardwareAssetHasLocation')
    
    WHERE VRS.Operating_System_Name_and0 NOT LIKE '%Server%' AND
        vGSOS.[Version0] = @OSBuild 
            ORDER BY BIOS.SerialNumber0 ASC
```

**SECOND TRY**

```
DECLARE @OSBuild AS VARCHAR(100)='10.0.19042';

with a as (
    SELECT
      VRS.[ResourceID] AS [ResourceID]
      , VRS.[Name0] AS [Computername]
      , VRS.[Resource_Domain_OR_Workgr0] AS [Domain]
      , BIOS.SerialNumber0 AS [Serialnumber]
      , case RT.RelationshipTypeName
          when 'Cireson.AssetManagement.HardwareAssetHasOrganization'
          then 'Organization'
          when 'Cireson.AssetManagement.HardwareAssetHasLocation'
          then 'Location'
        end as RelTypeName
      , BMEt.Name
      
    FROM [SERVER02].[dbo].[v_R_System] as VRS
      JOIN [SERVER02].[dbo].[v_GS_OPERATING_SYSTEM] AS vGSOS
        ON vGSOS.[ResourceID] = VRS.[ResourceID] 
      JOIN [SERVER02].[dbo].v_GS_PC_BIOS AS BIOS
        ON BIOS.[ResourceID] = VRS.[ResourceID]
      JOIN [SERVER01].[ServiceManager].[dbo].[MT_Cireson$AssetManagement$HardwareAsset] AS HWA
        ON BIOS.SerialNumber0 = HWA.SerialNumber_C8CF2E89_7A83_1C26_0AD0_887DF9140D5A COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS

      JOIN [SERVER01].[ServiceManager].[dbo].relationship AS rel
        ON rel.SourceEntityId = HWA.BaseManagedEntityId
      JOIN [SERVER01].[ServiceManager].[dbo].[RelationshipType] AS RT
        ON rel.RelationshipTypeId = RT.RelationshipTypeId 
          AND RT.RelationshipTypeName IN ('Cireson.AssetManagement.HardwareAssetHasOrganization','Cireson.AssetManagement.HardwareAssetHasLocation')
      JOIN [SERVER01].[ServiceManager].[dbo].[BaseManagedEntity] AS BMEt
        ON rel.TargetEntityId = BMEt.BaseManagedEntityId
        
    WHERE VRS.Operating_System_Name_and0 NOT LIKE '%Server%'
      AND vGSOS.[Version0] = @OSBuild
)

select *
from a
pivot (
 max(Name) for RelTypeName in (
    [Location],
    [Organization]
  )
) as q
ORDER BY [Serialnumber] ASC
```

Gives Error:

```
Msg 319, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'. If this statement is a common table expression, an xmlnamespaces clause or a change tracking context clause, the previous statement must be terminated with a semicolon.

Completion time: 2021-06-24T13:37:17.2405171+02:00
```

**NEW ERROR**

```
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 40
Invalid column name 'Name'.

Completion time: 2021-06-24T13:58:13.3559097+02:00
```

Comment: `inner join` (which is also a simple `join` without any additional keyword) returns rows from both the tables that satisfy a join predicate. So of course you get the name from the relationship of type you request. Do individual join for each type or use conditional aggregation to pivot types to column values depending on the size of output dataset: for mass processing I will go for aggregation, for single item individual joins should be faster

Comment: Thanks for answering astentx but Isn't what you described what I mentioned I've tried? I tried joining it twice but then I get no data?
I'm sorry I don't know how aggregation works but I will Google it and see if I can manage  it.

Comment: You need to use two joins to the same table with different aliases (say `RT1` and `RT2`). I will post the answer later if no one help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may also use [pivot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-ver15) to turn rows to columns, if one `RelationshipType` may have only one value:

```
with a as (
    SELECT
      VRS.[ResourceID] AS [ResourceID]
      , VRS.[Name0] AS [Computername]
      , VRS.[Resource_Domain_OR_Workgr0] AS [Domain]
      , BIOS.SerialNumber0 AS [Serialnumber]
      , case RT.RelationshipTypeName
          when 'Cireson.AssetManagement.HardwareAssetHasOrganization'
          then 'Organization'
          when 'Cireson.AssetManagement.HardwareAssetHasLocation'
          then 'Location'
        end as RelTypeName
      , BMEt.Name
      
    FROM [SERVER02].[dbo].[v_R_System] as VRS
      JOIN [SERVER02].[dbo].[v_GS_OPERATING_SYSTEM] AS vGSOS
        on vGSOS.[ResourceID] = VRS.[ResourceID] 
      JOIN [SERVER02].[dbo].v_GS_PC_BIOS AS BIOS
        ON BIOS.[ResourceID] = VRS.[ResourceID]
      JOIN [SERVER01].[ServiceManager].[dbo].[MT_Cireson$AssetManagement$HardwareAsset] AS HWA
        ON BIOS.SerialNumber0 = HWA.SerialNumber_C8CF2E89_7A83_1C26_0AD0_887DF9140D5A COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS

      JOIN [SERVER01].[ServiceManager].[dbo].relationship AS rel
        ON rel.SourceEntityId = HWA.BaseManagedEntityId
      JOIN [SERVER01].[ServiceManager].[dbo].[RelationshipType] AS RT
        ON rel.RelationshipTypeId = RT.RelationshipTypeId 
          AND RT.RelationshipTypeName IN ('Cireson.AssetManagement.HardwareAssetHasOrganization','Cireson.AssetManagement.HardwareAssetHasLocation')
      JOIN [SERVER01].[ServiceManager].[dbo].[BaseManagedEntity] AS BMEt
        ON rel.TargetEntityId = BMEt.BaseManagedEntityId
        
    WHERE VRS.Operating_System_Name_and0 NOT LIKE '%Server%'
      AND vGSOS.[Version0] = @OSBuild
)

select *
from a
pivot (
  max(Name) for RelTypeName in (
    [Location],
    [Organization]
  )
) as q
ORDER BY [Serialnumber] ASC
```

*db<>fiddle with some simplified example [is here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017l&fiddle=adfb99fd24dd36e590a53a6f8a75f8c5)*

Comment: Thanks for helping. I've tried your code and it gave error (as stated above). Alltough I'm not sure if  I understood you correctly. If RelationshipTypeName ...Organisation I recieve only one value and if ...Location I get only one but another value.

Comment: @MarkusSacramento `with` accompanied by `declare` should be preceded with semicolon. That's why you sometimes may see scripts like `;with something as (...`. What about values: as long as you join on either `...Location` or `... Organisation`, you'll have rows of both the types. Then pivot will turn them both to columns, where you'll get the value for each type (enumerated in `in` part of `pivot`), aggregated with `max` function. So if there's no either value, there will be `null` in the corresponding column.

Comment: As long as you may have only one row of each type, `max` will not affect the output, because `max` or `min` of a single value will produce this exact value. If you may have more that one value (of Location, for example), then `max` will obviously return maximal (according to default collation), which *may* be not what you expect. Then two-join approach is the only way, because it will produce as much combinations as there are different combinations of `..Location` and `... Organisation`. Hope I was clear enough in the above text)

Comment: Thanks again. I think I understood. Null value is great if value is missing. I added the semicolon and got a little bit further. Now it complains about column name 'Name' in the pivot. Which table according to your query contains the column name 'Name'? Maybe the column is named differently I just need to make sure I am in correct table.

Comment: Never mind I managed to get it working! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want two sets of joins:

```
INNER JOIN
[SERVER01].[ServiceManager].[dbo].[BaseManagedEntity] BMEt
ON rel.TargetEntityId = BMEt.BaseManagedEntityId INNER JOIN
[SERVER01].[ServiceManager].[dbo].[RelationshipType] RT
ON rel.RelationshipTypeId = RT.RelationshipTypeId AND
   RT.RelationshipTypeName = 'Cireson.AssetManagement.HardwareAssetHasOrganization' INNER JOIN
[SERVER01].[ServiceManager].[dbo].[BaseManagedEntity] BMEt2
ON rel2.TargetEntityId = BMEt2.BaseManagedEntityId INNER JOIN
[SERVER01].[ServiceManager].[dbo].[RelationshipType] RT2
ON rel.RelationshipTypeId = RT2.RelationshipTypeId AND
   RT2.RelationshipTypeName = 'Cireson.AssetManagement.HardwareAssetHasLocation';
```

One note:  Usually this is done using `LEFT JOIN` rather than `INNER JOIN`.  Without sample data, desired results, and a clear explanation of the query logic it is a bit hard to say, but I'm pretty sure you need outer joins here.

Comment: Correct I want to get data from same table twice. From RelationsshipTypeName I choose to retrieve either 'Cireson.AssetManagement.HardwareAssetHasLocation' or 'Cireson.AssetManagement.HardwareAssetHasOrganization'.
Your post I have tried and I recieve no data.

Comment: @MarkusSacramento . . . Use `LEFT JOIN`s as the answer advises.